# Fancybox is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, graph, legend

I was following an example from **Python Data Science Handbook** which is plotting a simple graph. Its supposed to use fancybox on labels but it is not working as per the example.

The code is:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, np.sin(x), '-b', label = 'Sine');
ax.plot(x, np.cos(x), '--r', label = 'Cosine');
ax.axis('equal')
leg = ax.legend(fancybox = True, framealpha = 1, shadow = True, borderpad = 1)
```

What I am supposed to get is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWcvJ.png)

what I am getting is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieHri.png)

Even after copy pasting the whole code from book, fancybox is not working. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
My matplotlib version is 3.3.1
```

Comment: I get the desired result using matplotlib 3.2.1. Two possibilities: 1) you have a `frameon=False` somewhere (in your rcParams, for example), or 2) it is a bug in matplotlib that needs fixing.

Comment: Yeah, I had `frameon=False` , I didn't realize i set it to False before. It worked when I set it back to True.